# how to add database values in report.rdlc chart c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to put the values inside the chart

[image: im trying to put the values inside the chart]

How do I add the database value in the chart on report.rdlc? Here's my query:

```
SELECT Therapist, COUNT(*) AS magnitude FROM dbinfo.tblorder GROUP BY Therapist ORDER BY magnitude DESC
```

So how do I add the "magnitude" in the chart values? Thank you

Comment: check this link. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/how-to-create-rdlc-charts-and-complete-series-of-all-charts/